# Type '{ one: string; two: string; three: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

**This is the Array of Items i need to use**

```
const prices = [
  {
    name: "Standard",
    price: "149EGP",
    features: [
      {
        one: "add 2500 Order Monthly",
        two: "Add Unlimted Products And Categories",
        three: "add 20 other Employees",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Premium",
    price: "349EGP",
    features: [
      {
        one: "add 2500 Order Monthly",
        two: "Add Unlimted Products And Categories",
        three: "add 20 other Employees",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Enterprise",
    price: "499EGP",
    features: [
      {
        one: "add 2500 Order Monthly",
        two: "Add Unlimted Products And Categories",
        three: "add 20 other Employees",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**Trying to map the array to add all the elements to the page**
and the main array is working well and shown in page
the error here is i can't access the nested object (features) to show the features it shown to me the error in the title

```
`const pricingCard = prices.map(({ name, price, features }) => {
  const featuresMap = features.map((feature) => {
    <>
      <li className='flex items-center space-x-3'>
        <svg
          className='flex-shrink-0 w-5 h-5 text-green-500 dark:text-green-400'
          fill='currentColor'
          viewBox='0 0 20 20'
          xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
          <path
            fill-rule='evenodd'
            d='M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z'
            clip-rule='evenodd'></path>
        </svg>
        <span>{feature}</span>
      </li>
      ;
    </>;
  });`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
<span>{feature}</span>
```

Has no way of knowing how to *display* your `feature` object.  What the error is trying to say is that at `{feature}` it's expecting a node or markup element of some kind, or at least a primitive value.  But instead you're giving it an object, and it doesn't know what to do with that.

You can display each property on that object individually.  For example:

```
<span>
  <ul>
    <li>{feature.one}</li>
    <li>{feature.two}</li>
    <li>{feature.three}</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Or however you want to organize and display those values in your markup.  But what you can't do is rely on the system to figure out a way to display it for you automatically.